# How to view git commits when local branch is ahead of origin Commits

Tags: git, git-commit, git-log

I want to view git commits when my branch is ahead of origin branch.

i tried `git log`  it returns all commits. but, i want to view only `ahead commits` from branch to origin/branch

here what i mean,

> ```
> On branch permissions
> Your branch is ahead of 'upstream/permissions' by 2 commits.
>   (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
>
> nothing to commit, working directory clean
> ```

in this case i want to view 2 commits

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run log, you can tell it one or more commits whose history you want to include, and also one or more commits whose history you want to *exclude*.  (When you don't specify, git assumes you mean "the history of the commit I have currently checked out.)

In your case, you want the history of `permissions` (the local branch you're on), but you want to exclude the history of `upstream/permissions` (the remote reference that tells you where the `origin` remote's copy of the `permissions` branch was, when last you talked to `origin`.

So one option would be

```
git log permissions ^upstream/permissions
```

There are shorthand notations for this, like

```
git log upstream/permissions..permissions
```

Answer (score 7):

Simple,

```
git log branch...origin/branch
```

Or little more beautiful :

```
git log --graph --color --decorate --oneline branch...origin/branch
```

Comment: can you explain? i tried develop as well replaced with my branch it shows an error

Comment: tried, git log br_name origin/br_name  and this too git log develop...origin/develop

Comment: Use `git log br_name...origin/br_name` - you are forgetting the `...`. Besides you don't have develop branch, that's why second command is failing.

Comment: i tried to to but it returns all. brname..origin/brname shows all but origin/brname..brname works fine

Comment: i upvote for your graphical representation thanks :) it looks like pycharm